# How to rename the uploaded files in PHP

Tags: php

```
extract($_POST);
$error=array();
$extension=array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");
foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name) {
    $file_name=$_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];
    $file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"".$_POST['property_builder']."/".$_POST['property_city'].""."/".$_POST['property_location'].""."/".$_POST['property_type']."/".'Images-'.$_POST['property_name']."/".$file_name);


$content_to_write .= '<img src="Images-'.$_POST['property_name'].'/'.$file_name.'" alt="'.$file_name.'" title="'.$file_name.'" height="400" width="600">';
}
```

In the above code, I am unable to rename the uploaded files.. Please help me out as how to rename all the uploaded files by user...

User, just uploads 5 files, I want 5 text boxes asking for 5 filenames.. and save them accordingly.

Comment: Can you show the error here?

Comment: `if(!move_uploaded_file($source_path,$target_path)){
 $error = error_get_last();
 print_r($error);
}`

Answer (score 2):

You supposed to change following code

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"".$_POST['property_builder']."/".$_POST['property_city'].""."/".$_POST['property_location'].""."/".$_POST['property_type']."/".'Images-'.$_POST['property_name']."/".$file_name);
```

with

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = $_POST['filename']."."end($temp); // this filename is the name of field you have given in your text fields. If you have not given extension name you have to include that too.
// Make sure your path is currect where you're saving your file
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"./pathtomainimagefolder".$_POST['property_builder']."/".$_POST['property_city']."/".$_POST['property_location']."/".$_POST['property_type']."/".'Images-'.$_POST['property_name']."/".$newfilename);
```

Just make sure the file path. I just wrote smaple based on your path.